# Capturing a Session variable in Session_OnStart - Global.asa

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, global-asax

I'm trying to use the users session to process the code in my global.asa:

```
Sub Session_OnStart
  sAdmin = Session("Admin")      
  Application("Admin") = sAdmin
```

The `Session("Admin")` is not empty, but the `Application("Admin")` always comes up empty when I check it.  Is there a reason I'm not able to capture the users session variable in the `Session_OnStart` section of the global.asa?

When I do this `Application("Admin")` doesn't come up empty, it comes up as `hi`

```
Sub Session_OnStart
  Application("Admin") = "hi"
```

What do I have to do to capture the users session value in the global.asa?

Comment: What are you expecting the value of sAdmin to be? Sessoin_start fires when a new session is created thus Session("Admin") should be empty.

Comment: The Admin name like `Bob`, I want to trigger the code only if the user is an Admin.

Comment: Does the code need to run only once or on every request?

Comment: When an Admin session is created.

Comment: What you trying won't work. Your storing the admin flag is a session object but you accessing it before the user session gets created. You need to move the code someplace else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you try to set "by reference" assignment so that `Application("Admin")` will change when `Session("Admin")` changes. I fear such thing is not possible in classic ASP.

The only elegant way I can think of is adding helper method that will be included in all pages:

```
Sub AssignAdminSession(value)
    Session("Admin") = value
    Application("Admin") = value
End Sub
```

Then instead of just `Session("Admin") = "something"` have everywhere:

```
Call AssignAdminSession("value here")
```